# How could monitor every process on web application server?

Tags: .net, web-applications, iis-7, monitoring

I want to find some Application that could tell me some statistics information about every thing that happen in my server application...

I have a web application written with C#.net and sqlserver ,it sets up on winsows Server 2008R2 and works on LAN,I want to find out witch process take too long,or every process cycle on server,How could monitor this things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks all.I Finaly find the microsoft Advanced Logging,it is great tools for IIS ,after that I could Analyze the result with WebLogExpert and sql server so nice.the link that help me is here :

http://perftesting.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20To%3A%20Use%20IIS%20Log%20Files%20In%20Performance%20Testing&ProjectName=perftesting

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of an all-encompassing solution, but I know there are several packages out there that allow you monitor and log various events in your ASP.NET application.

Off the top of my head, [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) is a relatively drop-in-able solution that has alot of pluggable logging facilities. You can drop it in with Nuget.

ASP.NET also comes with its own application health monitoring tools, simply called [ASP.NET Health Monitoring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bb398933.aspx). Haven't worked much with that, but it may be a useful tool.